# Broken dpkg, sudo, tty and apt

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I've managed to break my terminals completely and am scared to reboot. I force removed some stuff using dpkg, since I installed a .rpm which didn't work out, and accidentally removed the wrong one. I have a terminal open, but each time I type sudo I get this:

```
sed: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ls: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Which is kinda frustrating. I have a .deb which I need to install now (containing the correct libpcre.so's), but I've no idea if it's even possible with my current configuration to get them out.

I managed to find a few files that do still exist, which I'm hoping I can point stuff at.

```
josh@desktop:~/Downloads$ !122
locate libpcre.so
sed: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
```

Any recommendations? I'd rather not do a clean install if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to boot from the bootable USB I used to install the system, find all files whose names contain `pcre`. At this point, I mounted the existing installations partition to `/home/user/tmp/` installed sublime text (easier to create commands to run en-mass from that), then for each file in the list (except those in the man / docs directories) ran `sudo cp /path/to/current/file /home/user/mounteddirectory/path/to/current/file` which copied the required files and let me boot. Boot then proceeded.

After that, I found that apt gave me some errors but at the very least it ran. I ran `sudo apt update` which prompted me that some stuff wasn't installed properly, so I tried the suggested `sudo apt -f install` which gave me an error about some links. To resolve this, I eventually copied the .deb file which `sudo apt -f install` dumped the name of and path to (should contain libpcre3, in this case), to cwd (user root) and ran `sudo dpkg --force-all -i libpcre~~~~~.deb` which fixed all the other problems.